# Copiar archivos desde una lista contenida en otro archivo

Tags: linux, consola, búsquedas

Tengo un archivo en *Linux* que contiene una lista de nombres de 500 archivos, quiero detectar si existen en mi disco duro, y luego ir copiándolos a una carpeta destino llamada, por ejemplo, `Encontrados`.

El archivo que contiene la lista de archivos a copiar tiene una estructura como la siguiente (cada ruta es una línea).

> /home/usuario/ejemplo/archivo_1.txt
>   /home/usuario/proyectos/archivo_2.png

La única manera en que se me ocurrió resolverlo (en mi caso lo hice en *Bash*) es:

```
cat archivosAencontrar.txt|find / -exec cp /ENCONTRADOS
```

Comment: En principio `find` no acepta datos por la entrada estándar, por lo que esa línea `cat` no tendría ningún efecto sobre el comportamiento del `find`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En principio `find` no acepta datos por la entrada estándar, por lo que los datos enviados por el `cat` al `find` no tienen ningún efecto sobre su funcionamiento.

Prueba con esta expresión:

```
xargs -I '{}' find . -name '{}' < archivos.txt | xargs -I '{}' cp '{}' /tmp/
```

Fíjate que no es necesario usar `cat`, basta con una redirección de entrada. Usamos `{}` como contenedor de cada línea de `archivos.txt` y por cada resultado encontrado por `find` repetimos el proceso para hacer la copia.

Uso el modificador `-I` para configurar el patrón de sustitución:

> **-I replace-str**
>
> Replace occurrences of `replace-str` in the initial-arguments with names read from standard input.
>
> Also, 
>   unquoted  blanks  do
>   not terminate input items; instead the separator is the newline character.
>
> Implies -x and -L 1.

En castellano:

> **-I cadena-reemplazo**
>
> Reemplaza las ocurrencias de `cadena-reemplazo` en los argumentos con los nombres obtenidos de le entrada estándar.
>
> Además, espacios en blanco sin escapar no terminan los elementos de entrada; en su lugar el separador es el carácter de nueva línea.
>
> Implica -x y -L 1.

Una versión reducida en la que uso `=` como contenedor de cada línea de datos sería:

```
xargs -I '=' find . -name '=' -exec cp {} /tmp/ \; < archivos.txt
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto!!!
No hubiera encontrado la solución ni en un millón de años. Es un comando demasiado complejo para mi entendimiento.

Intentaré comprenderlo, no me entra en la cabeza que find pueda buscar algo sin un cat, ahí solo veo una redirección, pero lo importante es que funciona.

Comment: Gracias! Me alegro que te funcione :) Si quieres te mando enlaces a documentación sobre redirecciones, tuberías, etc... `cat` tiene como parámetro una lista de archivos que concatena, y da su salida a la salida estándar. Pero si sólo quieres un archivo, entonces directamente puedes usar el operador `<` para pasar dicho archivo a la entrada estándar del programa.

Comment: Pues sí, te agradezco si compartes enlaces o me dices qué buscar para aprender cómo lo has hecho. La verdad pensé que se iban a reír de mí por no saber esto o me iban a tachar de no esforzarme. Ya hay gente que se ríe por decir que uso linux en vez de windows.

Comment: Echa un vistazo a éste: http://dep.fie.umich.mx/~stinoco/archivos/Tuberias.pdf

Comment: Gracias!!! Hay muy buen material en ese enlace, me pondré enseguida a estudiarlo. Un abrazo OscarGarcia

Comment: Mira también http://es.tldp.org/Tutoriales/doc-tutorial-linux/tutorial-gnu-linux.pdf busca tutoriales de linux y encontrarás mucho material del que aprender. Suerte y bienvenido! :D